# i want copy data from table to another without duplicate using triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, copy, database-trigger

i have two tables 
in table number one it's add rows every moment depend on user insert
and in  table number two i want to copy every row has been added on table one but with specific criteria
and also table number two have some additional columns i need them later
i want do that by triggers but i don't know how to do that

i'v already try stored procedure but not automatically

```html
INSERT INTO ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS2
(
    [BARCODE]
    , [CREATEDDATETIME]
 ,[Name]
    , [ITEMID]
    , [NETAMOUNTINCLTAX]
    , [QTY]
    , [STAFFID]
    , [TERMINALID]
    , [TRANSDATE]
 ,[PERIODICPERCENTAGEDISCOUNT]
 ,[ReceiptID]
)
SELECT ab.[BARCODE]
    , ab.[CREATEDDATETIME]
 ,[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[NAME]
    , ab.[ITEMID]
    , ab.[PRICE]
    , ab.[QTY]
    , ab.[STAFFID]
    , ab.[TERMINALID]
    , ab.[TRANSDATE]
 , ab.[PERIODICPERCENTAGEDISCOUNT]
 ,ab.RECEIPTID
FROM ax.RetailTransactionSalesTrans ab
inner join [ax].[INVENTTABLE] on ab.[ITEMID] =[ax].[INVENTTABLE].[ITEMID]
inner join [ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION] on [ax].[INVENTTABLE].PRODUCT =[ax].[ECORESPRODUCTTRANSLATION].[PRODUCT]
LEFT JOIN ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS2 a ON 
a.[BARCODE] = ab.[BARCODE]
    AND a.[CREATEDDATETIME] = ab.[CREATEDDATETIME]
    AND a.[ITEMID] = ab.[ITEMID] 
    AND a.[NETAMOUNTINCLTAX] = ab.[PRICE]
    AND a.[QTY] = ab.[QTY] 
    AND a.[STAFFID] = ab.[STAFFID] 
    AND a.[TERMINALID] = ab.[TERMINALID] 
    AND a.[TRANSDATE] = ab.[TRANSDATE]
 AND a.[PERIODICPERCENTAGEDISCOUNT]=ab.[PERIODICPERCENTAGEDISCOUNT]
 and a.Process=null and a.Checked=null and a.[Select]=null
 where ab.[QTY]>0 and ab.[RECEIPTID]!='' and ab.[TRANSDATE] >= DATEADD(day, @daycount*-1, GetDate())
 and NOT EXISTS(select * from ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS2 where [CREATEDDATETIME] = ab.[CREATEDDATETIME])
```

i want to convert that as trigger but i don't how do that

note: @daycount i take it from another table but i pass that by my program

Comment: please refer to documentation on triggers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below and edit the needed columns , the idea is **FROM Inserted** you can select all rows that inserted to the main table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRetailTransactionSalesTrans ON RetailTransactionSalesTrans
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS2
    SELECT [BARCODE]
        ,[CREATEDDATETIME]
        ,[Name]
        ,[ITEMID]
        ,[NETAMOUNTINCLTAX]
        ,[QTY]
        ,[STAFFID]
        ,[TERMINALID]
        ,[TRANSDATE]
        ,[PERIODICPERCENTAGEDISCOUNT]
        ,[ReceiptID]
    FROM Inserted;
END
```

Comment: because i see this error 

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TRetailTransactionSalesTrans, Line 3
Invalid column name 'Name'.
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TRetailTransactionSalesTrans, Line 2
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: table tow have 4 additional columns more than table one but those columns not exist on table one and no relation with table one 

and Name column come from another table which have join inner